# Gap between Glide ImageView elements Android Studio

Tags: java, android, mobile, android-glide

In my Android app I'd like to add function for loading images from memory - code below:

```
LinearLayout linlay = findViewById(R.id.linlay);
Button addImagesButton = findViewById(R.id.addImagesButton);

ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> mChoosePhoto = registerForActivityResult(
                new ActivityResultContracts.GetMultipleContents(),
                new ActivityResultCallback<List<Uri>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onActivityResult(List<Uri> result) {
                        res = result;
                        for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {
                            ImageView imageView = new ImageView(SomeActivity.this);
                            imageView.setPadding(0,0,0,0);
                            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                            imageView.setLayoutParams(params);
                            Glide.with(ReportForLocationActivity.this)
                                    .load(result.get(i))
                                    .into(imageView);

                            linlay.addView(imageView);
                        }
                    }
                });

addImagesButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
    mChoosePhoto.launch("image/*");
});
```

Everything works correctly, but between ImageView elements added to Glide there is a big gap - how can I make it smaller?[Screen from emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Okinl.png)

I've tried to change margin and padding settings but it did not work.

Answer (score 1):

Solved!

```
LinearLayout linlay = findViewById(R.id.linlay);
Button addImagesButton = findViewById(R.id.addImagesButton);

ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> mChoosePhoto = registerForActivityResult(
                new ActivityResultContracts.GetMultipleContents(),
                new ActivityResultCallback<List<Uri>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onActivityResult(List<Uri> result) {
                        res = result;
                        for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {
                            ImageView imageView = new ImageView(SomeActivity.this);
                            imageView.setPadding(0,0,0,0);
                            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                            imageView.setLayoutParams(params);
                            imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
                            Glide.with(ReportForLocationActivity.this)
                                    .load(result.get(i))
                                    .into(imageView);

                            linlay.addView(imageView);
                        }
                    }
                });

addImagesButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
    mChoosePhoto.launch("image/*");
});
```